# Replace & character in a string

Tags: c#

i'm a little ashamed to ask this but when i want to use the Replace method to get rid off a '&' character it does not work.

```
string name = gResults[i].Replace("type=unique",""); --> WORKS
string name = gResults[i].Replace("&type=unique",""); --> KO.
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong with that character?
Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it as far as I know. What do you mean by _does not work_ exactly? Can you please be _more_ specific?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. This is unclear. The second line you show _will_ replace `&type=unique` into an empty string in the input, if it is present. Ampersands have no special meaning in C# strings.

Comment: What is the error (if there is one) ?

Comment: with the &, the &type=unique is not replaced by empty string

Comment: you SURE it's really `&`, and not `&amp;` being rendered as `&`?

Comment: Read the link under [mcve]. We can't see your input, so we can't answer this.

Comment: Please give an example of a `gResults[i]` value which is not working, or even better a unit test that is failing.

Comment: Are you really trying to replace the entire string `&type=unique` with an empty string...?

Comment: what you are asking in regards to replacing the `&` sign with string.Empty have you tried the following 
`string name = gResults[i].Replace("&",string.Empty);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string name = gResults[i].Replace("&&type=unique","");
```

This will escape the ampersand in the .Net world.

If that isn't successful I would try to split the string on the ampersand into two strings and use the part that you want.